# Password Generator

Tags: popularity-contest, random

Task:
Make a program that generate a 24-digit password.

Rule:

- None of the character can be repeated more than once
- Must include at least one upcase, one locase, one number, five special character.
- The answer which got most votes win.

SPECIAL CHARACTER LIST:
`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\:";'<>?,./ or other

Comment: Looks like I edited the post at the same time as you. Did you change "most votes" into "50 votes the earliest"? If yes, then I think my edit has undone that. Also, if you really did that edit, then I don't think that's a good criteria. It is also possible that an answer doesn't get 50 upvotes at all.

Comment: Yes, @ProgramFOX.

Comment: But I Added This:None of the character can be repeated more than once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## bash

You might need to tune `A-M` by increasing or decreasing the range to meet specs.

```
ls -al ~ | grep -o . | tr -d A-M | sort | uniq | head -n 24 | xargs | sed 's/ //g'
```

E.g:

```
$ ls -al ~ | grep -o . | tr -d A-M | sort | uniq | head -n 24 | xargs | sed 's/ //g'

+-.0123456789:@OPSTU_a
```